# Suspending and resuming threads for Azure bus service

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am new to thread programming in python. I am trying to read message from azure service bus, the message may or may not be present in the queue. So this is the logic I come up with

```
bus_service = ServiceBusService(
service_namespace='eventservice',
shared_access_key_name='key-name',
shared_access_key_value='password')

logger.info("Created bus_service object")

def service_bus_listner(callback):
    """thread worker function"""
    global currentBackOff
    logger.info('Started listening to service bus messages')
    current_thread = threading.currentThread()
    while True:
        msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message('python-test', 'AllMessages', peek_lock=True)
        if msg.body is not None:
            currentBackOff = 0
            process_message(msg)
        else:
            if currentBackOff < maxBackOff:
                currentBackOff += 10

            logger.info("No message to process. Backing off for {0} seconds".format(currentBackOff))
            time.sleep(currentBackOff)


def process_message(msg):
    try:
        message = json.loads(msg.body.decode())
        message_id = message.get('Id')
        logger.info("Received message with id: %s" % message_id)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    finally:
        msg.delete()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=service_bus_listner, args=(process_message, ))
    thread.start()
```

So if the message queue is empty service_bus_listner waits for some specified seconds (controlled by `currentBackOff` variable) and retry till it receives a message and the value of `currentBackOff` variable is set to 0. The function `service_bus_listner` is running in a separate thread.

I have gone through the documentation of `time.sleep` function here [Time.sleep Document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) and it says that calling of this function ***Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.***

Does calling `time.sleep` in `service_bus_listner` functions free up the CPU for the specified time (in seconds).

I want to know the most ideal way(in terms of Memory and CPU utilization) of pausing and resuming a thread in python.

Comment: As for `time.sleep`, it should do what you describe as it uses system clock interrupts. And I feel that using `global` anywhere is a code smell, implying that the code should be reorganized into classes.